# Linux Apache Razor

Tags: linux, apache, razor, mono, mod-mono

I've successfully installed mod mono in my Apache, I can now run `aspx` files but not `cshtml` files. When I try to open `cshtml` files, razor code appears in the browser. I tried adding `cshtml` extension in `mod_mono.conf` and `mod_mono_auto.conf` but still `cshtml` is not recognized.

I Also tried adding necessary binaries like `System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll` and I got an error when accessing `aspx`:

```
Access to the path "/var/www/bin" is denied.
```

Did I miss something?